# Rails3: Use joined table's data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm trying to access my joined table data but alas..

For example association between authors and books, author have many books:
I'm using `join` funtion to join the author table to the books table in order to access the author's `author_name` attribute

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  attr_accessible :author_name
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end

random_author = Author.first
books = random_author.books.where(id > 5).joins(:author) #this should make all author attributes available to each book, right?

book_1 = books.first
book_1.author_name
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `author_name' for #<Book:0x111111>
```

Of course using the association would work: `book_1.author.author_name` but that will require another query, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I mean the `joins` operation joins the author's data- there must be a way to access it right?

p.s. I can use `includes` method. and eager load the author data as well, but since I'm just needing a single attribute- is there a way to accomplished it with only a `joins` method? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
.select('books.*, author.name AS author_name')
```

So your query becomes

```
books = random_author.books.where(id > 5).joins(:author).select('books.*, author.name AS author_name')
```